# Scribe - LinkedIn OAuth giving me NoSuchElementException

Tags: android, oauth, scribe

I am new to android and trying to implement scribe oauth login for Linkedin.  Getting a `NoSuchElementException` on my `Verifier`, any help would be appreciated.

```
mLinkedIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                            .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
                            .apiKey("APIKEY")
                            .apiSecret("APISecret")
                            .build();

                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    // String search = in.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("=== LinkedIn's OAuth Workflow ===");
                    System.out.println();

                    // Obtain the Request Token
                    System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
                    Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
                    System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
                    System.out.println();

                    System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
                    System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
                    System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
                    System.out.print(">>");
                    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
                    System.out.println();

                    // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
                    System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
                    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                    System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
                    System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
                    System.out.println();

                    // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
                    System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
                    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
                    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
                    Response response = request.send();
                    System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(response.getBody());

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with Scribe! :)");
                }



        }).start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Was this fixed, if yes, please let me know how.